# How to make flutter app draw below android navigation?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here is my flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

When I launch my flutter app (it's a clean start project, I have just removed the `Center` widget) in my emulator I see this:

[image: Flutter App navbar over app]

I would like my app to showned below the android app bar without having to add some padding. Like this:

[image: Flutter App navbar not over app]

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the widget with `SafeArea`. SafeArea is a widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.

```
return SafeArea( // here
 child: Scaffold(
   body: Text()
 )
);
```

More about [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)